# C# Windows APP: Adding UIElements to Grid/GridView

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

im coding a Windows 8 appliation with C#, but im stuck since friday with some UI adjustment.
I have a GridView and i want to add UIElements on the GridView, so no problem:

```
foreach(TouchpadButton btn in m_ButtonList)
{  
   mainGrid.Items.Add(btn);
}
```

Thats how i add them, but im reading them out of an XML and the XML defines also the position of the Button (Row/Col).
So my Question is how do i add these Buttons on the specific Row/Column?

Here is how my  GridView look like, i didnt changed yet anything (XAML):

```
 <GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="443,327,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="398" Height="223"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a way but forgot to update this:
If you want to to set a Button for example in a specific row/col then you have to do this:

```
Button btn = new Button(); // Empty Button
int Row = 0;
int Col = 1;
Grid.SetRow(btn,Row);
Grid.SetColumn(btn,Col);
```

You have to be sure that the Row/Column also exists so you can use:

```
if(mainGrid.RowDefinitions.ElementAt(Row) != null && mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.ElemantAt(Col) != null)
{

 Grid.SetRow(btn,Row);
 Grid.SetColumn(btn,Col);
}
```

Of course you do that all before you add the UIElement to the Grid!